# Ошибка при составлении конструктора с типом char

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio

Компилятор MSVS  ругается на входные параметры конструктора структуры у которых тип char

```
typedef struct dhcp_packet_struct {
    u_int8_t  op;                   /* packet type */
    u_int8_t  htype;                /* type of hardware address for this machine (Ethernet, etc) */
    u_int8_t  hlen;                 /* length of hardware address (of this machine) */
    u_int8_t  hops;                 /* hops */
    u_int32_t xid;                  /* random transaction id number - chosen by this machine */
    u_int16_t secs;                 /* seconds used in timing */
    u_int16_t flags;                /* flags */
    struct in_addr ciaddr;          /* IP address of this machine (if we already have one) */
    struct in_addr yiaddr;          /* IP address of this machine (offered by the DHCP server) */
    struct in_addr siaddr;          /* IP address of DHCP server */
    struct in_addr giaddr;          /* IP address of DHCP relay */
    unsigned char chaddr[MAX_DHCP_CHADDR_LENGTH];      /* hardware address of this machine */
    char sname[MAX_DHCP_SNAME_LENGTH];    /* name of DHCP server */
    char file[MAX_DHCP_FILE_LENGTH];      /* boot file name (used for diskless booting?) */
    char options[MAX_DHCP_OPTIONS_LENGTH];  /* options */

    dhcp_packet_struct() {}
    dhcp_packet_struct(u_int8_t op, 
                       u_int8_t htype, 
                       u_int8_t hlen, 
                       u_int8_t hops, 
                       u_int32_t xid, 
                       u_int16_t secs, 
                       u_int16_t flags, 
                       in_addr ciaddr, 
                       in_addr yiaddr, 
                       in_addr siaddr, 
                       in_addr giaddr, 
                       unsigned char chaddr[MAX_DHCP_CHADDR_LENGTH], 
                       char sname[MAX_DHCP_SNAME_LENGTH], 
                       char file[MAX_DHCP_FILE_LENGTH], 
                       char options[MAX_DHCP_OPTIONS_LENGTH])
        :
                    op(op), 
                    htype(htype),
                    hlen(hlen),
                    hops(hops),
                    xid(xid),
                    secs(secs),
                    flags(flags),
                    ciaddr(ciaddr),
                    yiaddr(yiaddr), 
                    siaddr(siaddr),
                    giaddr(giaddr),
                    chaddr(chaddr),
                    sname(sname),
                    file(file),
                    options(options) {
    }
}dhcp_packet;
```

Компилятор пишет ошибку:

> error C2075: "dhcp_packet_struct::chaddr": для инициализации массива требуется список инициализаторов, заключенный в фигурные скобки

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: В с / с++ нет возможности передавать массивы в качестве параметров функций и нет возможности инициализировать / присваивать массивы значением другого массива. Используйте `std::array`. А еще у вас параметры функции имеют те же названия, что и поля класса.

Comment: Я таки не понял, это у вас все же С или С++?

Comment: @Harry видимо `c++`, конструкторы же. А структуру наверное дёрнули откуда-то и добавили конструктуторы для удобства. Только `typedef` там лишний, и без него всё огонь будет.

Comment: @vegorov О том и спич - каким боком тут метка "С"?

Comment: @Harry ну это не ко мне, я на этом ресурсе ещё не настолько освоился. В прошлый раз когда я правил сообщение и менял метку (то ли с `c` на `c++` то ли наоборот) правку приняли но кто-то оставил едкий комментарий `бесполезная правка` или типа того. Зато с меткой `c` кто-то из сишников может ответить как копировать массивы с помощью `memcpy`

Comment: @vegorov Да я не с претензией, а просто поясняю...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример с `std::array`, упомянутом в комментарии:

```
#include <array>
#include <iostream>

#define MAX_SIZE 16

struct A{
    using ChAddr = std::array<unsigned char, MAX_SIZE>;
    ChAddr m_chaddr;
    A(const ChAddr& chaddr):
        m_chaddr{chaddr}
    {}
    void print(){
        for (const auto& e: m_chaddr){
            std::cout << (int)e << std::endl;
        }
    }

};

int main()
{
    A a({'1', '2', '3', 0xFE});
    a.print();
    return 0;
}
```

Вывод:

```
49
50
51
254
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
0
```

Comment: Выдает ошибку: недопустимый полный тип

Comment: @НиколаКривошея У меня `gcc version 7.2.0 (Ubuntu 7.2.0-1ubuntu1~16.04)`, под VisualStudio не знаю что будет.

Comment: @НиколаКривошея воспользуйтесь советом из другого [ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/815413/286405)

Answer (score -1):

Вам не нужно полагаться на:

```
                chaddr(chaddr),
                sname(sname),
                file(file),
                options(options)
```

, а в теле конструктора скопировать данные в массивы структуры.

Comment: Кто минусил, хоть бы комментарий оставил.

Comment: наверное они хотели видеть здесь конкретный пример (код), а не только совет `в теле конструктора скопировать данные в массивы структуры`.  C `memcpy` или типа того.